# How to crop image in circular shape in android?

Tags: android, imageview, crop

I want to crop selected image in circular shape from gallery. I have checked few solution for same question, but I am not able to solve my issue. Maximum solution provide for custom shape imageview means provide a .xml file or class extends with Imageview but I want to crop image like following screenshot or Instagram app crop image.

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView  Use this class for rounded imageviews.  It is awesome.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-with-rounded-corners/3292810#3292810

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind to use a library.Use SimpleCropView library,it has circle crop mode.
https://github.com/IsseiAoki/SimpleCropView